# No overload matches this call in angular ngrx props

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngrx

in angular application when defining actions and using props, I get "No overload matches this call ..." on props

```
import { createAction, props } from "@ngrx/store";
export const storeCurrentDashboard = createAction(
  "[effect] store current dashboard in state",
  props<Dashboard>()// here i get the error
);
```

and the Dashboard class is like below

```
export class Dashboard {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  type: DashboardType; // the problem is this property
  blocks?: any[];
}
export enum DashboardType {
  Private = "Private",
  Shared = "Shared",
...
}
```

and if i remove "type" property which is an enum every thing is ok.
why props have problem with enum types?

compiler error:

```
   ERROR in ...: error TS2345: Argument of type '"type property is not allowed in action creators"'
 is not assignable to parameter of type 'FunctionWithParametersType<any[], object>'.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> and if i remove "type" property which is an enum every thing is ok. why props have problem with enum types?

Yes `type`is like a reserved word for `NgRx`, in the `createAction` call, it matches the first param.